# Clustered primary key on long varchar?

Tags: sql-server

Usually, we avoid creating clustered index on wide columns. There is a table

```
create table T (K varchar(255) primary key noclustered, ....)
```

However, most of the values (99%) in the column `K` have the length less than 10. Is it good to create clustered index on it?

Comment: You would need a pretty good reason to want that for your clustering key. Why is a nonclustered index not satisfactory? Do you have any other indexes on this table?

Comment: If you will have only that one, clustered index - then it's not optimal by any means, but you could probably live with it. But if you have multiple non-clustered indices as well, remember: the column(s) of the clustered index are **repeatedly stored** in each and every single non-clustered index as well. So if you have several NCI, and millions of rows - you're potentially **wasting** a whole lot of disk (and RAM!) space with your wide and suboptimal clustered index

Comment: @sqlzim yes there are 8 other indexes

Comment: @marc_s I know the storage of other index. However most of values in K is very narrow.

Comment: But if you have **8 other indexes**, and 8 x 100 million rows, and your average string is 12 bytes long - then you're still wasting 8 x 100 million x 8 bytes (when compared to an `INT` clustered index)  ... that's **a lot of disk space** - not to mention that this also needs to be present in your server's RAM when the pages are loaded into buffer pool

Comment: See Kimberly Tripp's excellent post [Disk space is cheap - that's **NOT** the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/disk-space-is-cheap/) about the importance of a **good design** of your clustered index - and while you're at it, read everything she has to say about indexing in SQL Server - she' the *Queen Of Indexing* after all :-)